# Счетчик запущенных Task

Tags: c#, task, counter

В своем приложении использую много фоновых задач.

Нужен счетчик активных задач. Для того чтобы корректно закрывать приложение дождавшись нулевого значения.
Использую вместо Task.Factory.StartNew( ... );   TasksHub.StartNewTask( ... );

```
public static class TasksHub
{
    private static int tasksActive = 0;

    public static event EventHandler TasksActiveIsUpdated;

    public static int TasksActive
    {
        get
        {
            return tasksActive;
        }
        set
        {
            tasksActive = value;
            OnTasksActiveIsUpdated(null);
        }
    }

    public static void OnTasksActiveIsUpdated(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = TasksActiveIsUpdated;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { handler(null, e); });
            //handler(null, e);
        }
    }


    public static Task StartNewTask(Action action)
    {
        lock (new object()) TasksActive++;
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            action();
            lock (new object()) TasksActive--;
        });
    }

    public static Task<T> StartNewTask<T>(Func<T> function)
    {
        lock (new object()) TasksActive++;
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            var result = function();
            lock (new object()) TasksActive--;
            return result;
        });
    }

}
```

Проблема в следующем. Счетчик TasksActive долгий период времени может иметь значение 1. Это понятно какая-то задача подвисает.
Но TasksActive принимает и отрицательные значения.
Каким образом TasksActive становится отрицательным я не могу понять.

Comment: Странный способ блокировок.. нужно сделать private readonly переменную и через неё локать критические участки, а не создавать новый объект. А лучше имхо использовать Interlocked.Increment

Comment: `lock (new object()) TasksActive++;` - это, по сути, отсутсвие блокировки

Comment: Дожидаться окончания всех тасков можно с помощью Task.WhenAll

Answer (score 0):

Осмелюсь предложить такой вариант

```
static class TasksHub
{
    private static bool _closed = false;
    private static CountdownEvent _countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(1);

    public static Task StartNewTask(Action action)
    {
        _countdownEvent.AddCount();
        try {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                try {
                    action();
                }
                finally {
                    _countdownEvent.Signal();
                }
            });
        }
        catch {
            // если StartNew бросит исключение надо обязательно уменьшить счетчик
            _countdownEvent.Signal();
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static Task<T> StartNewTask<T>(Func<T> function)
    {
        _countdownEvent.AddCount();
        try {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                try {
                    return function();
                }
                finally {
                    _countdownEvent.Signal();
                }
            });
        }
        catch {
            // если StartNew бросит исключение надо обязательно уменьшить счетчик
            _countdownEvent.Signal();
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static int TasksCount
    {
        get {
            return _countdownEvent.CurrentCount - (!_closed ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }

    public static void CloseAndWait()
    {
        CloseAndWait(-1);
    }

    public static bool CloseAndWait(int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        if (!_closed) {
            _countdownEvent.Signal();
            _closed = true;
        }

        return _countdownEvent.Wait(millisecondsTimeout);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TasksHub.StartNewTask(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        });

        TasksHub.StartNewTask(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        });

        var b1 = TasksHub.CloseAndWait(10);
        TasksHub.CloseAndWait();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь.
В итоге переделал в следующий вид.

```
public static class TasksHub
{
    private static int tasksActive = 0;
    public static event EventHandler TasksActiveIsUpdated;
    public static int TasksActive
    {
        get
        {
            return tasksActive;
        }
    }

    public static void OnTasksActiveIsUpdated(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = TasksActiveIsUpdated;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { handler(null, e); });
        }
    }

    private static void TasksActiveIncrement()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref tasksActive);
        OnTasksActiveIsUpdated(null);
    }

    private static void TasksActiveDecrement()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref tasksActive);
        OnTasksActiveIsUpdated(null);
    }


    public static int GetTasksActive()
    {
        return tasksActive;
    }

    public static Task StartNewTask(Action action)
    {
        int startTimestamp = (int)DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        TasksActiveIncrement();
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            action();
            TasksActiveDecrement();
        });
    }

    public static Task<T> StartNewTask<T>(Func<T> function)
    {
        int startTimestamp = (int)DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        TasksActiveIncrement();
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            var result = function();
            TasksActiveDecrement();
            return result;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 return tasksActive; - по хорошему Interlocked.Read(). 2  StartNew, по факту не "задача уже запущена", а "задача поставлена в пул.", а значит TasksActiveIncrement(); лучше делать внутри. (хотя если будет семафор, то нет) 3 при исключении в action(); не сработает TasksActiveDecrement();. нужен try..finally